# Dynamically Show/Hide Wizard Navigation Controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, navigation, code-behind, wizard

I have a `<asp:Wizard>` control with 6 or so steps. In the first 3 steps, I want to hide the default Wizard navigation (Next button, etc.), as each WizardStep's contents will handle that. For the last 3 or so steps, if possible, I want to use the built-in navigation.

I've modified the `<StepNavigationTemplate>` contents, but that alone doesn't cut it, because it affects all steps. Here are my options:

- Find a way to dynamically show or hide the StepNavigation from the codebehind. (I feel like this might be best -- is it possible?)
- Use `StepType` with `<StartNavigationTemplate>`, `<StepNavigationTemplate>`, and `<FinishNavigationTemplate>` to switch between navigation options (marking multiple steps as "start" or "finish" feels like it's abusing the mechanism)
- Switch to a `<asp:MultiView>` and handle navigation manually (I'd rather not do this)

Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second option is what i would go with. i dont think this is abusing the mechanism. all you are doing is saying that this particular step is the first step.

you will achive the desired outcome by simply creating your own template (inheriting from itemplate) and setting your wizard control StartTemplate to be this. The other templates can just stay the same as they are.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did: mark the first 3 steps as StartNavigationTemplate. Works perfectly. Thanks for your input!